# adjusting laravel's timeout settings for basic access authentication

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, basic-authentication

According to https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#http-basic-authentication Laravel supports basic HTTP authentication.

According to https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-6.2 "*Clients that have been idle for an extended period, following which the server might wish to cause the client to re-prompt the user for credentials*".

My questions is...  can the length of this "extended period" be adjusted in Laravel? If so how would I do that? And what happens if a new Docker container is launched and then a client who had been connecting to one container suddenly connects to this new Docker container? Will the client be reprompted to login in that scenario? If so how could I make it so that it wouldn't do that?

I'm running Laravel 5.5.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first question: the config/session.php has a 'lifetime' setting (overridable by the .env file setting, which has a setting for 'Session Timeout' (typically 120 minutes)).

You can use Auth::check() in your middleware to see if the session expired, and if so you can redirect back to the 'Login' page.

This link shows you how to use it https://laravel.io/forum/09-10-2015-l5-detect-session-expiration

Look at SynRJ's reply

Regarding your 2nd question, I am unable to help.